# Stripe Webhook not returning user_id

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, stripe-connect

I have a web application that is listening to webhook to the accounts they are connected to via oauth and for some reason every webhook that is coming in doesn't have the `user_id` attribute on them.

```
{ 
  id: 'evt_18USWeLQuocIBkVl4x3RYTYn',
  object: 'event',
  api_version: '2016-06-15',
  created: 1467859564,
  data:
   { object:
      { id: 'ch_18USWdLQuocIBkVlfev2xN9n',
        object: 'charge',
        amount: 300,
        amount_refunded: 0,
        application_fee: null,
        balance_transaction: 'txn_18USWeLQuocIBkVlYKlhfYl7',
        captured: true,
        created: 1467859563,
        currency: 'usd',
        customer: null,
        description: '',
        destination: null,
        dispute: null,
        failure_code: null,
        failure_message: null,
        fraud_details: {},
        invoice: null,
        livemode: false,
        metadata: {},
        order: null,
        paid: true,
        receipt_email: null,
        receipt_number: null,
        refunded: false,
        refunds: [Object],
        shipping: null,
        source: [Object],
        source_transfer: null,
        statement_descriptor: null,
        status: 'succeeded' } },
  livemode: false,
  pending_webhooks: 2,
  request: 'req_8m0X3GgVB7IWpM',
  type: 'charge.succeeded'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different types of [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) that can be set up:

- "Account" webhooks will receive events that happen on your own account
- "Connect" webhooks will receive events that happen on any account that is connected to your platform

Only events sent to "Connect" webhooks will include the [`user_id`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#webhooks) field.

If you're receiving events without a `user_id` field, then that means the event happened on your own account, and was sent to you via an "Account" endpoint rather than a "Connect" endpoint.

Comment: A little late on the response but this was the issue. I misread the docs. Thank you so much